# sending millions of short messages over tcp socket in golang

Tags: go, tcp, microservices

I'm writing two services in golang that need to send to each other about 2 million messages per second. Each message is about 50 bytes, so throughput should only be about 100MB/s. I want to use tcp for this. However, results are very slow. I configured SetNoDelay(false) to make sure that data is buffered before sending, but that didn't make any difference.

I can only send about 50k messages per second, and message size doesn't matter too much, so I assume the code is blocking somewhere. Here's my test code:

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import (
    //"strings"
    "time"
)

func startserver() {
    fmt.Println("Launching server...")
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
    conn, _ := ln.Accept()

    for {
        bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        //fmt.Println(message)
        //newmessage := strings.ToUpper(message)
        //conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
    }
}

func startclient() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second) // so that server has time to start
    servAddr := "127.0.0.1:8081"
    tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", servAddr)
    conn, _ := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    conn.SetNoDelay(false)
    conn.SetWriteBuffer(10000)
    msg := "abc\n"
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        conn.Write([]byte(msg))
        //bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        //fmt.Print("Message from server: ", response)
    }
    fmt.Println("took:", time.Since(start))
}

func main() {
    go startserver()
    startclient()
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: aside from performance, you're losing data and causing extra allocations in the server by discarding the `bufio.Reader`, you're not checking errors, not waiting for the server to complete, and only timing the write calls which are not going to be flushed before the process exits.

Comment: I just tried a bufWriter, and speed indeed increased significantly (500ms for a million writes). So I guess that's the way to do it. In my original code I was handling errors, just tried to simplify the example as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syscalls are expensive, and writing data over loopback is very fast, so this is essentially just timing how fast you can make 1 million calls to `write`.

Making lots of small reads and writes is the primary use case for using buffered io. Wrapping the normal `net.TCPConn` in a [`bufio.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewWriter) will provide the expected performance increase.

Comment: I have an issue, When I'm sending large data over TCP, the parsing is failing, the same data if i send in small size this become success, Why is this happening?